# Android Network/Wireless Scanner - Any Assistance

Tags: java, android, android-layout, networking, android-networking

I am looking at building a network scanner that will tell the user what type of security is implemented on the network that they are connected too, for example they are using WPA, the application would tell the user this and tell them how insecure it is. I was looking to see if anyone had any ideas, or if anyone had done anything similar that they could help me?
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks
Chris.

Comment: This is much too broad for StackOverflow. Please edit your question and explain specific things that are causing you problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

and here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html